# Which Perl XML parser can add data to particular nodes?

Tags: xml, perl

I need to add a few lines in an XML file at a particular node, in Perl. So, I need to search for a particular node and then add those lines. Which parser would you recommend for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend [XML::Twig](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/XML::Twig).  It can modify all elements of a certain name, or just one element. It has excellent documentation, including a tutorial... and the module author is always on-call :)

This is a simple example which will append some text to all elements named "article":

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

my $xmlStr = <<XML;
<foo>
    <article>ME ME ME</article>
    <article>HE HE</article>
    <particle>ME TOO</particle>
</foo>
XML

my $twig= XML::Twig->new(
    twig_handlers => { article => \&article }
);
$twig->parse($xmlStr);
$twig->print();
print "\n";
exit;

sub article {
    my ($twig, $art) = @_;
    my $stuff = $art->text();  # get the text of article
    $stuff .= ' YOU YOU YOU';
    $art->set_text($stuff);
}
```

Comment: I understand your handler is just an example, but in case you didn't know: you could also use $art->suffix( ' YOU YOU YOU'); Oh, and XML::Twig->new(...) is preferred over the deprecated new XML::Twig. But I like to nitpick :--)

Comment: I'm glad you like to nitpick!  I was unaware of both of these points.  I'll fix the constructor call, but leave the suffix out... just so the OP sees that TIMTOWTDI.  Thanks.